# How is it that a user with a multi-year network-wide suspension was user #3?

Tags: discussion, users

We don't even have a page full of users yet:

[image]

I understand that Adam was the first user, which makes sense because he's the developer that made the site go live. Henry was the second user to join, which makes sense since Henry is always keen about new beta sites. However [user #3](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/users/3/jeremy) is on a multi-year network-wide ban. How could such a user be aware of the Private Beta? The email was sent out to users that committed to the Area51 proposal, but suspended users can't commit to proposals.

Comment: Anyone that follows the goings-on of SE would be able to see that it launched, I imagine. Merely navigating to the newly-created site while logged into an SE account allows you to join the private beta. It seems that Jeremy continues to be interested in newly created sites and was able to join. As soon as he did, the network wide suspension kicked in and applied a suspension on this site.

Comment: One has to know that the site went up in order to "merely navigate to the newly-created site". I wonder how someone that was not informed by email could know that the site went up within just minutes.

Comment: There's an [Area 51 feed](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/beta) for new beta sites that some chatrooms subscribe to. If they also visit various chatrooms that have configured their room's feeds to output new beta sites to them, they may have seen the message that a new site had launched. The feed is pretty quick to report new sites having launched. They wouldn't be able to talk in those chatrooms due to the suspension, but they'd be able to read the messages in the rooms they're in.

Comment: Can you name one chatroom that uses that feed? Feeds also take about 15 minutes on average to land in a chatroom.

Answer (score 4):

The announcement on Area 51 Discussions [Congratulations to Bioacoustics on completing the Commitment phase!](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32767/89927) says:

> During private beta, the site will not be visible from the rest of the network but may be accessed by visiting the Area 51 proposal or **through a link shared by an existing user**.

Maybe the user created a new account to join the Bioacoustics proposal and then used the private link to get to the private beta under his primary account.

Comment: This seems much more likely than the theory presented in the comments on the question.